# Git: cannot delete local branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I was trying to track a remote branch with `$ git checkout -b --track global/master`, and git created a branch named "--track".  Now, when I run `$ git branch -D --track` it won't delete the branch.  I believe Git is parsing the last argument, `--track`, as a `git-branch` subcommand flag, not a branch name.

I attempted to quote the branch name with `$ git branch -D '--track'` and escape the leading hyphen with `$ git branch -D \--track`.

How can I delete the "--track" branch?

Comment: I cannot create branch with this name, git complains.

Comment: Have you tried `$ git branch -D -- --track` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Uli Köhler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2597135/uli-kohler) already said:

```
git branch -D -- --track
```

The command will work to delete your branch.

Comment: Didn't work for me
`git branch -D -- --track
error: branch '--track' not found.`